# how to make a div responsive with respect to the image

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to develop a web page. In that I am supposed to place an image at the center of the page. Below that image I placed an div so that by clicking on that div certain items will be displayed.My problem is that when the size of the window reduced the image will become responsive,but not that div. I want to make both of them responsive.Here is my code

index.html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="top:-125px;">
                <img id="i1" class="img-responsive" src="img/2.png" height="600" width="600" alt="">
                <div style="padding-left:45%;top:-250px;">
                    <div id="triangle-up"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my css

```
#triangle-up {

position: absolute;
bottom:0;
left: 46%; 
padding: 5px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
border-left: 60px solid transparent;
border-right: 60px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 67px solid grey;
}
.container
{
position: relative;
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: Use tables and place image in that, you can make both responsive and image can be centered always

Comment: @Shadow let me check. Thank you for the quick replay

Comment: you are placing triangle-up div as absolute position but you should not. If you are developing a responsive layout you should not use absolute positioning. Do not use table for layout and move all your inline style to the css. Also, why do you use a container div for triangle-up with top=-250px?

Comment: maybe a jsfiddle would help out to better illustrate your problem

Comment: @LelioFaieta I used trainagle-up with top=250px for placing it in correct position.

Comment: If you remove absolute position you will realize you don't need it.

Comment: @AbuPR just update your code with jsfiddle and you will get the better and effective responce

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to set up width of your div to 100% and max-width as pixels amount that you don't want your div to grow any larger than.